# Read google apps related to company from google play store -Infinite scrolling

Tags: java

I am trying to read all the apps placed in google play store for a particular company in java.Is there any framework available in java to do that.I tried by using jSoup to crawl the web page.But that page is loading as infinite scrolling.

Please suggest me on this.Thanks in advance....

Comment: you need to figure out first how that infinite scrolling works. not related to appengine per se or google apps.

Comment: Can you post the url you're trying to fetch?